# Why can't the left hand side of an assignment be an increment expression?

Tags: java, arrays

Could any one please tell me the meaning of "++" with array in the following code in Java:

```
   int [ ] arr = new int[ 4 ];
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[ i ] = i + 1;
       System.out.println(arr[ i ]++);
   }
```

what is `arr[ i ]++` meaning in above code, and why we can't do like:

```
arr[ i ]++ = i + 1;
```

Comment: Never seen such coding style (with spaces inside square braces) in java code.

Comment: As a side note, the bytecode for the ++ operator depends on whether it's used on a local int variable or not, and on whether the result is used or not. The simplest case is of a bare increment of a local int variable, where a single increment instruction is generated. Your case of postincrementing an array member generates some of the most complex bytecode. (I can't comment on any JIT transformation.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator being discussed here is called the postfix increment operator ([JLS 15.14.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.14.2)). It is specified to behave as follows:

> 1. At run time, if evaluation of the operand expression completes abruptly, then the postfix increment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no incrementation occurs.
> 2. Otherwise, the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable.
>
>    1. Before the addition, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable.
>    2. If necessary, the sum is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3) and/or subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to the type of the variable before it is stored.
> 3. *The value of the postfix increment expression is **the value** of the variable before the new value is stored*.

The last point is the key for this question: the reason why you can't do `arr[i]++ = v;` is the same exact reason why you can't do `x++ = v;`; the postfix increment expression returns a *value*, not a *variable*.

From [JLS 15.1 Evaluation, Denotation and Result](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.1):

> When an expression in a program is evaluated (executed), the result denotes one of three things:
>
> - A variable [...] (in C, this would be called an lvalue)
> - A value [...]
> - Nothing (the expression is said to be void)

An assignment needs a *variable* on the left hand side, and a value is NOT a variable, and that's why you can't do `x++ = v;`.

From [JLS 15.26 Assignment Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26):

> *The result of the first operand of an assignment operator must be a variable, or a compile-time error occurs*. This operand may be a named variable [...], or it may be a computed variable, as can result from a field [...] or an array access. [...]

The following snippet shows erroneous attempts to assign to a *value*, going from rather subtle to more obvious:

```
int v = 42;
int x = 0;
x = v;        // OKAY!
x++ = v;      // illegal!
(x + 0) = v;  // illegal!
(x * 1) = v;  // illegal!
42 = v;       // illegal!
   // Error message: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"
```

Note that you *can* use the postfix increment operator *somewhere* on the left hand side of an assignment operator, as long as the final result is a variable.

```
int[] arr = new int[3];
int i = 0;
arr[i++] = 2;
arr[i++] = 3;
arr[i++] = 5;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // prints "[2, 3, 5]"
```

Answer (score 2):

`arr[i]++` means "increase the value of `arr[i]` by 1" and return the old value. So your code first sets `arr[i]` to `i+1` using `arr[ i ] = i + 1;`. It then increases it to `i + 2` using `arr[ i ]++` and prints the value it had *before* it was increased the second time, i.e. `i + 1`.

You can't use `arr[ i ] = arr[i] + 1;` instead because it means "increase the value of `arr[i]` by 1 and return the new value".

You can't do `arr[ i ]++ = i + 1;` because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The code doesn't first increase the value of arr[i]. That would be `arr[i] = arr[i] + 1`. But it says `arr[i] = i + 1`. That is different.

Answer (score 2):

The code `System.out.println(arr[i]++)` means this:

```
int tmp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
System.out.println(tmp);
```

Your second example doesn't make sense because you can't use the `++` operator on a value.

Answer (score 1):

The ++ operator has nothing to do with arrays.  It increments any integer variable (or more generally, any lvalue) by 1.  It's the same as the i++ in the loop.

You can write either ++x or x++.  These both increment x, but they have different values: ++x returns the new value of x and x++ returns the old value.  Thus, your code prints 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of 2, 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[ i ]++` increases arr[i] by 1. It could be like:

```
arr[i] = i + 1;
```

As for `arr[ i ]++ = i + 1;` please do not try to write such code. Even if it compiles it will be puzzle for you or for others.

PS I would prefer:

```
++arr[i];
```

Comment: but `++arr[i]` will print a different result as `arr[i]++`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would do increasing:`++arr[i]` in one line and printing in another. I think this will be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

arr[i]++ is increase the value of arr[i] by one and assign

as for `arr[ i ]++ = i + 1;` This phrase means something entirely different, I don't know that it is even valid java to be honest. I would, if it works, incriment the value at arr[i] and then asign it to the index + 1;